# C programming error handling

Tags: c, error-handling, pthreads

I want my code to be able to handle the error cases, such as unsuccessful return of functions. For instance,`pthread_create`,normally I use the function herebelow:

```
int thread_check1;
 pthread_t function;
 thread_check1 = pthread_create( &function, NULL, function_function,  NULL);
if(thread_check1 != 0){
   fprintf(stderr, "pthread_create error\n");
   exit(1);
}
```

Considering the error cases, would it be correct to call the same function till it returns 0(for this specific function) as it is done below?

```
thread_check1 = pthread_create( &function, NULL, function_function,  NULL);
while(thread_check1 != 0){
    thread_check1 = pthread_create( &function, NULL, function_function,  NULL);
}
```

Can I apply the same logic to the other C functions that returns a value? Otherwise, how would you suggest to handle error cases (for the function returns) without exiting from the program?

Comment: That all depends on your requirements.

Comment: exiting your program like this isn't a that good idea.

Comment: @tsabz: How would you know? Maybe it's appropriate, maybe it isn't. There's no way to tell without the requirements.

Comment: Usually, I never call exit() on my programs. Returning a certain value for a check function and adapt the behaviour of the program depending on this value, until it reaches the main return.

Comment: @tsabz: It can get complicated fast. If there's no way to recover from the error, I don't see a point of returning into `main` (considering you may be far in the call stack). Logging the error and exiting is simpler and usually enough.

Comment: @netcoder I agree. I may have not developed deep enough C programs to judge though. It will probably depend on each case btw. It's just a matter of preferences, I simply don't really like exiting like this, I feel it's a bit too harsh

Comment: `man perror`.  There is no excuse for `fprintf( stderr,  "pthread_create error\n");` which is the classic example of a useless error message.

Comment: @netcoder, as a user, I would hate a program that would crash as soon as there is error. Even if you can't proceed, I would rather have the programming running and I exit it myself after it tells me I don't have enough resources. A popup error message followed by crash, even if logical by your design, is simply annoying.

Comment: @Shahbaz: That's very hypothetical. That's considering you can actually show a popup. Like I said, it depends on the requirement, there's no definitive good or bad here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* do that, but more properly. Assume there is function `f` which has different return values. You can do as follows:

```
tries_left = 1000;
do
{
    ret = f(params);
    if (ret == OK)
        break;
    else if (ret == SOMETHING_UNRECOVERABLE)
        /* break with failure */
    else if (ret == SOMETHING_FIXABLE)
        /* fix params */
    else
        /* sleep a little */
} while (--tries_left);
```

There are many things to consider here:

- *Avoid infinite loop*. If there is something inherently wrong, you wouldn't want to get stuck in a loop. So after some tries, you would want to break and fail. This is where `tries_left` comes into play.
- *Fail if unrecoverable*. If the error tells you that the problem is not fixable, stop trying. For example if you are trying to mount a drive and it tells you `/dev/sda6` doesn't exist, there is no point in retrying.
- *Try actually handling the problem*. In some cases, you may be able to try different parameters. For example if you are trying to create a backup file and you can't, you can try changing the directory or name of the file and try again.
- *Don't use 100% CPU*. If you want to retry, at least give some breathing room in between tries for whatever problem there was to go away, or in the very least to avoid using maximum CPU.

In the end, to avoid repeating yourself if you have different functions that need to be handled like this, you could put this whole thing in a macro and call it like `CHECK_AND_RETRY(f(params));`, assuming it is possible to understand what return value is unrecoverable and what is fixable no matter the function (kind of restrict, but there is no beautiful solution).

Answer (score 1):

As Joe already mentions it heavily depends on your requirements and on the method you want to use. Whenever something fails there's usually a reason. For example no more memory is available if `malloc` returns zero.

Trying to get new memory without actually using `free` under such circumstances will usually result in an infinite loop, so that's something you shouldn't do. On the other hand, when you want to open a file but it's currently blocked by another process you could do something similar.

However, keep in mind that such a loop will usually keep the CPU busy and slow down other processes/threads. Also you could use a thing between your current solutions and try several times before you exit:

```
error_count = 0;
thread_check1 = pthread_create( &function, NULL, function_function,  NULL);
while(thread_check1 != 0){
    sleep(1); // wait some time before we try again
    if(++error_count == 10){
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create thread\n");
        return 1;
    }
    thread_check1 = pthread_create( &function, NULL, function_function,  NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely not recommend handling errors like that. In the case there is a genuine problem you will be stuck in an infinite loop. An example is opening a file when it is already in use. I would say you should do one of the following:

- Print/Log the error and stop execution.
- Allow certain errors (Add a && to the if), this example would retry only if the error code is 3

  > if (thread_check1 != 0) {

  ```
       If (thread_check1 == 3) retry;
  ```

Answer (score 1):

What should be done in case of failure depends solely on your requirements.
Usually it will depend on type of the error (fatal, acceptable etc.) and it's impact on the program.
Getting back to your example, failure to create thread should probably be treated as fatal error since the issue that prevented it's creation will most likely not go away on second or third attempt (again, it depends on your requirements and environment) thus not looping is probably a better approach here. Yet again, whether you want to quit the program or not in case of failure is up to you - can your program continue running without this thread? If yes, terminating the program isn't necessary. Otherwise - terminate.